# Invariants ("checksums", "hash") for collection of integers

Tags: integer-sequences, data-analysis

The sum of a collection of integers doesn't depend on the order of the integers and can detect the corruption of one element of the collection (but multiple elements can get corrupted without their sum changing).

What are other invariants for a collection of integers, preferably those that can detect the corruption of multiple elements (while ignoring any changes in the order in which the elements are processed to calculate the invariant)?

Constraints: Number of integers is known, say, 16 Million <s>8 Million to 20 Million</s>. Integers in the collection need not be unique (so all could be 0). Integers fit in 25 bits (irrelevant if treated as signed or unsigned). Also, it suffices to detect an error (no need to correct it).

Comment: If you say non-negative integers then the sum of $2^a$ over the elements will detect any changes whatsoever. If you want positive and negative integers, there are easy fixes. Of course what one really wants is an invariant which is much smaller than the set members. That isn’t infallible

Comment: Order the integers, then compute a cryptographic hash.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen the chicken and egg issue is how does one know that some elements did not get corrupted in the process of being ordering.

Comment: You could also XOR the elements together, or sum hashes of the elements. If you combine multiple methods, the probability of a false negative drops rapidly to zero.

Comment: @KevinVentullo sum and XOR are cheap to implement in terms of area and time; what would be examples of hashes, and how would one calculate the probability of a false negative after the use of such invariants?

Comment: @user1823664 There are tons of different types of hashes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function. You should perhaps post the probability question as a standalone question. https://math.stackexchange.com/ is a better venue than MathOverflow for that.

Comment: The sum detects all single changes.  The sum and the sum of squares together detect all single and double changes.  And so on to higher powers, still linear-time to detect a bounded number of changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think Aaron Meyerowitz's comment is very on-point-- the OP probably needs to add some additional constraints to make the question non-trivial.  That said, in keeping with the spirit of the question, here's one perspective.

Let's make a few additional assumptions, hopefully in the spirit of the OP:

- There are $N$ items $x_1,...,x_N$, and $N$ is known.
- The items are non-negative.  (As Meyerowitz points out, this isn't really much of a restriction.)

Note that if we have a [symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) $p(x_1,...,x_N)$, then the order of the $x_i$ doesn't matter (i.e., the value of the polynomial is invariant).  We can now choose our favorite family of symmetric polynomials (e.g., the elementary symmetric polynomials), evaluate the first $k$ polynomials on our set, and use those values as our "hash".

Note that if the $x_i$ lived in some finite field instead of $\mathbb{Z}$, we essentially would be recreating [BCH error-correcting codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code).

---

EDIT

The OP's clarifications suggest a more concrete version of the above discussion.  It appears that we are trying to keep track of an unordered set $S$ of 25-bit strings, i.e., numbers in the range 0 to $2^{25}-1$; the size of the set is unknown but might plausibly be half the range.  In that case, we can represent $S$ very efficiently by a vector $v \in \mathbb{F}_{2}^{2^{25}}$ (i.e., a vector of $2^{25}$ bits), where the $i$-th bit is 1 if $i \in S$ and 0 otherwise.

Our problem then becomes one of considering error-detecting codes for $v$.

As suggested above, a $t$-error-correcting BCH code has distance $2t+1$ so can detect up to $2t$ errors.  (Note that an "error" in this encoding is either the insertion or removal of a number from $S$, so if we mutate one number into another, that counts as *two* errors: an insertion and a deletion.)

In practical terms, and using the notation on the BCH wikipedia page linked above, you'd use $q=2$, $c=1$, $m=26$, and if you store a hash of $\leq (2t+1)m/2$ bit corresponding to the syndrome of the BCH code, you'll be able to detect $\leq 2t$ errors.  If you were able to exclude a single element from $S$ (e.g., if the all-zero string never showed up), then you could reduce $m$ to 25 and save yourself a few bits.

In even more practical terms, if you're comfortable trading off some guarantee of correctness for much increased ease of implementation, you may prefer using a random code: construct $v$ as above, and generate $M$, a random $a \times 2^{25}$ matrix of bits.  Store $Mv$, which will be a string of $a$ bits.  This hash should perform nearly optimally as $a$ gets large enough (eventually beating the BCH code).

Comment: Updated the OP with constraints: N could be 8 million to 20 million; and items fit in 25 bits.

Comment: @user1823664 , if this addresses your question, please consider accepting the answer; if not, could you clarify what else you're looking for?

Comment: Elements of the collection could repeat and so $v$ doesn't determine $S$. The time budget for the entire operation is a few milliseconds and I am unable to come up with an effective way to realize $v$ (which needs 4 MegaBytes of memory), $M$, and the computation $Mv$.

Comment: @user1823664 : To your time budget concern: If you compute a hash (either through the BCH technique or a random matrix) while you originally construct S, both the speed and memory overhead should be extremely minimal-- FWIW, there is a very long history of real-time BCH encoding in communications.  As a sanity check, I just computed a 32-bit random hash on $2^{2^{25}}$ bits in 13 ms *in Python*; in a more performant language, it'd be faster.

Comment: @user1823664 : To your point about $S$ being a multi-set, not a set: If we give ourselves a strict upper limit of $N \leq 2^{2^{25}}-2$, then any multiset can be encoded in $2^{26}-1$ bits and we're back in business as above.  Let me know if you'd like me to sketch out how one would represent a multiset in bits.

Comment: please elaborate.